# assigning changing values using np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a way to pass a list to np.where so that the value being filled in can iterate through a list?

I am trying to create a new column in my dataframe. This new column needs to fill with different values based on an evaluation of a different column. I would normally do this with an np.where statement, but in this case the filled in value needs to iterate through a list.

i.e. for the below:

In each case where the value of test_case is in the df column 'old_data' I need to fill in the new column 'new_data' with a current value of list one, but each time that value also needs to increment through the list. The first time list_one would = 0, then the next time the condition is met list_one = 1, then 2. If the value doesnt match, then 0 is filled in instead.

```
test_case = [5]
list_one = [0, 1, 2]

df['new_data'] = np.where(test_case.isin(df['old_data']), list_one, 0)
```

Apologies if this post is hare to interpret. If I can add any other helpful information, I am happy to do so.

Thank You,
Tony Volpini

Comment: show us some sample data

Comment: `where` does not iterate or increment anything.  You give it 3 values, the `cond` and 2 values.  Those are arrays, list that can be made into arrays or Series.  It returns a new array (or maybe a Series).  Where shapes differ, it applies the numpy `broadcasting`.  Don't think 'incrementally'; think in terms of whole arrays or dataframe columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like the following:

```
# get the index
flag = df['old_data'].isin(test_case)
index_in_list = flag.cumsum() - 1
index_in_list = index_in_list.where(flag, np.nan)

# make the list into a series
series_one = pd.Series(list_one)
# now add the col
df['new_data'] = index_in_list.map(series_one).fillna(0)
```